# ASP.Net MVC 3: Multiple views/urls to one controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I'm trying to do the following with ASP.Net MVC 3:

I have a lot of "flat pages", which are basically html documents with no dot.net code attached.

I want to be able to request these pages through routed URLs, but I do not want to manually add each url to the routes.

So my question is: Is it possible to define a default route, which uses the same controller / action, but returns a view based on the URL requested ?

e.g. /home/about and /profile would use the views /home/about.cshtml and /profile.cshtml
but both would use the same controller and action, which pretty much just goes:

```
return View();
```

The reason: I'm doing all the pages of the site, which require dot.net code. However another person is doing all the "flat pages" (informative pages, etc.).

I want him to be able to add new pages, by just adding a cshtml file (like he would with webforms creating aspx files, with no code-behind)

This is necessary because I'd otherwise have to edit global.asax each and everytime he adds a page, which is quite often.

If this is not possible, I'll have to stick with webforms, which I really don't want to :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an action that takes as a parameter the name of the View; Something like this:

```
public ActionResult StaticPage(string viewName)
{
    return View(viewName);
}
```

Then define a route so the viewName isn't a parameter but instead is part of the URL:

```
"/Static/{viewName}"
```